# How to display content of a .html file in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two html files Editor.html and Test.html. I want to get the source code of Test.html file into a content editable div in Editor.html. Can I do this simply using java script?

Comment: I found a solution using HTML5 FileReader API with javascript. http://www.dotnetobject.com/Thread-reading-text-file-with-javascript-using-html5-FileReader Thanks for the replies..

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use iframes in that case. You can completely  get the iframe content with window.frames:

```
window.frames['iframe_name'].document.getElementById('div_in_iframe');
```

and you can replace the content of like usually.

Answer (score 1):

via ajax.

the [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) library makes light work of ajax

```
   <script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div id="myeditable" contenteditable="true"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

   /* the simplest method in the library */
    $("#myeditable").load("/test.html");

   </script>
```

There are other great javascript shorthand libraries too like [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)

Comment: The jquery load method seems very relevant but it didn't work for me. May be since I am implementing these as a local web application without hosting pages on a server.

Comment: locally, as in from a file server ? - use a local webserver to work in, there are many you can download, apache, wamp etc

Comment: There's no requirement to host these files in a webserver. I just want to use a webpage (Editor.html) to display the source code of another webpage (Test.html). Isn't it possible alone at client side?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this combined with whatever formatting you would like should do it. That is if you're looking for a way to write code and then click the button to pass the content to the iframe to see what comes out.

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>

    <script>
    function writer()
    {
    var page = document.getElementById('box').value
    document.getElementById('realbox').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = page
    }
    </script>
<body>

    <textarea rows ="50%" cols="100%" id='editbox'></textarea>
    <iframe style="background-color: red;" id='realbox' height="100%" width="100%">/iframe>
    <input type="button" onclick="writer()" value="write">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my problem is how to get the source code of another file for editing. As in here can I get an existing source code in my local directory into 'editbox'? 
Rendering it on an iframe is not necessary. I just want to open a given html source code in a webpage like we open files in IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `iframe` to load the webpage and then get its HTML code using javascript

```
<iframe src="test.html" style="display:none;" name="myFrame">
</iframe>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

and javascript is

```
<script>
var frame = window.frames["myFrame"].document;
var data = frame.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data;
</script>
```

This code will help to get all the HTML codes inside the  tag of your HTML file (In this case test.html).

But it will not print the  tag itself so to do so use:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<HTML>"+data"</HTML>";
```

But I recommend to use AJAX if possible by using Jquery Library.