# how to display another html in current html using asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ms-word, embed

Okay, so the idea is, someone uploads a word doc that has been turned into html file using words own saving system. Now I need to display said word doc in html form, modifie it and turn it back into docx form.

How can I (once i know the file specific location in a x directory) open it up in the current html without having to redirect to a new page?

Comment: Possibly closer to what you are looking for: [How to display content of a .html file in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690064/how-to-display-content-of-a-html-file-in-a-web-page/10690180), [Reading uploaded text file contents in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746837/reading-uploaded-text-file-contents-in-html)

Comment: yea it was the second one you gave me THANKS!!!